# ADD failed: file not found in build context

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am currently in the root of my project.

[image]

My goal is to try to run my front-end (front.py) and my back-end(API.py) in a docker container using the command

```
 sudo docker-compose -f project/docker/docker-compose.yml up -d
```

Unfortunately, it stops when it comes time to ADD ./requirements.txt / in the Dockerfile and cant seem to find it.

```
enter Building api-service-track-1
Sending build context to Docker daemon  3.072kB
Step 1/5 : FROM python:3
 ---> a42e2a4f3833
Step 2/5 : ADD ./requirements.txt /
ADD failed: file not found in build context or excluded by .dockerignore: stat requirements.txt: file does not exist
ERROR: Service 'api-service-track-1' failed to build : Build failed
```

requirements.txt contains

```
Flask==1.1.2
Flask-SQLAlchemy
Flask-Bcrypt
bleach
```

and this is my Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3
ADD ./requirements.txt /
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
WORKDIR /mnt/app/
CMD ["./run.sh", "./project/codeAPI/API.py", "./project/codeAPI/front.py"]
```

edit:
@DavidMaze Here's the code of my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  api-service-track-1:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    image: img_track1
    volumes:
      - ./:/mnt/app
    ports:
      - 5551:5551
```

edit 2:
This is the error I get after trying to launch docker.

```
Starting docker_api-service-track-1_1 ... error

ERROR: for docker_api-service-track-1_1  Cannot start service api-service-track-1: failed to create shim: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "./run.sh": stat ./run.sh: no such file or directory: unknown

ERROR: for api-service-track-1  Cannot start service api-service-track-1: failed to create shim: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "./run.sh": stat ./run.sh: no such file or directory: unknown
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

Does that mean I need to also change my run.sh directory?

edit 3:
run.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

export PYTHONPATH=$PWD/project/
echo python path is:
echo $PYTHONPATH

echo running the following python program
echo $@
python3 "$1"
python3 "$2"
```

Comment: What is in the `docker-compose.yml` file?  In particular, what directory do you pass as the `build:` or `build: { context: }` directory?  Could you move the Docker-related artifacts up to the top level of your repository?

Comment: Please edit the question to include the correctly-formatted YAML there.  If you're specifying `context: .`, though, that's relative to the location of the `docker-compose.yml` file, and you won't be able to `COPY` in any files from higher in the directory hierarchy.

Comment: Sorry I don't use StackOverFlow often. I just added the edit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Root Cause of the issue

Your context (as directory) does NOT include the ADDed file. This is the main issue.

## Details

there are 3 golden rules related to each others:

1. **Context** path is relative to the location of `docker-compose.yaml`
2. `ADD (or` COPY`) 1st argument is a path relative to that **context**
3. `ADD (or` COPY`) 1st argument is a path  must be INSIDE the context folder (Whether directly, or in the context's child directories)

Let's apply these 3 rules:

1. Your `docker-compose.yaml` is inside `./project/docker` & your context is `./`.

   => Your context is `./project/docker`
2. `ADD ./requirements.txt ...` & context `./project/docker`.

=> Means Your `requirements.txt` path is `./project/docker/requirements.txt` which is wrong, because it's exist in `../../requirements.txt` **relatively** to the context (`./project/docker`)

now let's say you fix the issue by putting the right path of requirements.txt :

```
ADD ../../requirements.txt .
```

3. The last fix will not work because even if we put the relative path of that ADDed file, **that file is not inside the context**.

## Solution

- The **context** must be changed to include all COPYed/ADDed files.
- COPYed/ADDed file paths must keep being relative to the new **context**.

**project/docker/docker-compose.yaml**

```
services:
  api-service-track-1:
    build:
      context: ../../ # context must include `requirements.txt`
      dockerfile: ./project/docker/Dockerfile # must be relative to context
```

**project/docker/Dockerfile**

```
# ./ is Relative to the context
ADD ./requirements.txt ...
```

Answer (score 2):

The context of the Dockerfile is relative to the current working directory of the Dockerfile.

Can you try moving `requirements.txt` to the `./projects/docker` sub-directory? or change the ADD command in your Dockerfile to `ADD ../../requirements.txt /`

Comment: I didn't want to change the current setup because I was following my school notes. I just added requirements.txt to the docker directory and I no longer have the error. Unfortunatly I have another error which I'll add to the post if you are able to help.

Comment: where is run.sh? I can't see it copied to the docker image?

Comment: run.sh is at the root of the project. I'll also add it to edit.

Comment: What I'm asking is if run.sh is actually copied to the image... you can probably check it by commenting out the CMD line in the dockerfile, rebuilding the image, and then run `docker run -it <image-id> /bin/bash` (obviously replacing image-id with the actual image id) and then navigating around in the container and looking at what files are there...

Comment: off the cuff, probably something like: 1. modify Dockerfile and comment out CMD line; 2. `docker build -t xyz <path-to-dockerfile>`; 3. `docker run -it xyz /bin/bash`. This will start a bash prompt in the container and you'll be able to see what's there...

Comment: I followed your instruction and I am currently in the bash prompt of the container. I used `echo * ` and `printf '%s\n' .* *` to find any files but it seems completely empty.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the current directory(from where you are running the command) as the relative path then give filepath of Dockerfile using flag -f and "." will represent the context.

> docker build . -f project/docker/Dockerfile